# Can we generate(in high dimension) uniformly distributed variables in a finite volume other than a cube?

Tags: multivariate, random-variables

I'd like to know if there is in the literature a (computationally cheap) algorithm to generate uniformly distributed variables in high dimension for a volume other than a cube and **without using rejection sampling**?

Thanks

Comment: Rejection sampling is the only general technique or doing this AFAIK.

Comment: @AlexC What about (linear) convex volumes?

Comment: @BobJansen by linear convex volumes, you mean volume delimited with at most 6 hyperplans?

Comment: No, a volume delimited by an arbitrary number of hyperplanes.

Comment: In dimension 2, how would you do it for the set of point {(x,y) / x<=y, 0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is suitable for mathematics stack or otherwise.